# volume above a rectangle $[0,2]\times[1,4]$ and under the paraboloid $z=x^2+4y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the volume above a rectangle $[0,2]\times [1,4]$ and under the paraboloid $z=x^2+4y^2$

The answer should be 17, but I found 176.

$$\int_1^4\int_0^2\int_0^{x^2+4y^2} dzdxdy$$

I think the $x$ limits isn't correct. I tried the cylinder coordinates, but I got some weird numbers.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_1^{\sqrt{20}}\int_0^{r^2\cos^2\theta+4r^2\sin^2\theta} rdzdrd\theta$$

$r = \sqrt{0^2+1^2} = 1, r = \sqrt{4^2+2^2} = \sqrt20$

$z = r^2 cos^2\theta + 4r^2 sin^2\theta$

then for $\theta$ the rectangle is only in the +xy plan

Comment: The first integral you wrote down ia a computation of volume, not (surface) area. Also, you described the rectangle $[0,2]\times [1,4]$ in polar coordinates incorrectly

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I just edited it.

Comment: I don't see where is my error.
$r^2= x^2+y^2$, $x = r cos \theta, y = r sin \theta$

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with the new limits? Perhaps if you do, you’ll notice something wrong

Comment: If you want to express this integral in cylindrical coordianates, you'll have to break this up into two integrals, and your bounds for $\theta$ will be $\arctan(1/2)\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. It's easier to compute this integral though in Cartesian form, and I'm getting 176 as well

Comment: To see why you need to break this up into two different integrals in cylindrical coordinates, you should draw a picture of the region and express $y=1,x=2,$ and $y=4$ in polar form

Comment: Alright, maybe just an error in my book... I'm gonna cry, I try to understand my error since 3 good hours.

Answer (score 1):

$z=x^2+4y^2\geq 0$ for all $x,y$ because a sum of squares is always positive.

Your integral integral is set up okay, I think it’s easiest to stick to rectangular coordinates for this particular case, and the answer is

$$\int_1^4\int_0^2x^2+4y^2dxdy=\int_1^4\frac{x^3}{3}+4xy^2\Bigg|_0^2dy=\int_1^4 \frac{8}{3}+8y^2dy=\frac{8y}{3}+\frac{8y^3}{3}\Bigg|_1^4=8+8\cdot 21= 176$$

Comment: $x$ is between 0 and 2 then you change for 1 and 2.

Comment: I was in the process of editing it! Sorry!

Comment: It’s easiest to stick to rectangular coordinates in this case because the function you are integrating is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ which is easy to do by the rule $\int x^a dx = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$ and the limits of integration are just numbers :)